# What is filling my /var/log/messages (db-k450-hd2-1 IngrianActivity)?

Tags: logging, syslog, disk-space-utilization

My /var/log/messages is getting full with the following logs and can't figure out what is writing the logs. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Jun 13 00:12:28 db-k450-hd2-2 IngrianActivity: [2020-06-13 00:12:28] INFO 10.7.114.45 [-] - 205012001322 KeyInfo kestrel.database.key3 [-] - [Success] [-]
Jun 13 00:12:28 db-k450-hd2-2 IngrianActivity: [2020-06-13 00:12:28] INFO 10.7.114.45 [-] - 205010003504 KeyInfo kestrel.database.key3 [-] - [Success] [-]
Jun 13 00:12:28 db-k450-hd2-2 IngrianActivity: [2020-06-13 00:12:28] INFO 10.7.114.45 [-] - 205009000002 Crypto kestrel.database.key3 [op#1 DECRYPT DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding] - [Success] [-]
Jun 13 00:12:28 db-k450-hd2-1 IngrianActivity: [2020-06-13 00:12:28] INFO 10.7.114.45 [-] - 205008000002 Crypto kestrel.database.key3 [op#1 DECRYPT DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding] - [Success] [-]
Jun 13 00:12:28 db-k450-hd2-2 IngrianActivity: [2020-06-13 00:12:28] INFO 10.7.114.44 [-] - 204148001137 KeyInfo kestrel.database.key3 [-] - [Success] [-]
Jun 13 00:12:28 db-k450-hd2-2 IngrianActivity: [2020-06-13 00:12:28] INFO 10.7.114.44 [-] - 204148001138 KeyInfo kestrel.database.key3 [-] - [Success] [-]
Jun 13 00:12:28 db-k450-hd2-1 IngrianActivity: [2020-06-13 00:12:28] INFO 10.7.114.44 [-] - 204141000002 Crypto kestrel.database.key3 [op#1 DECRYPT DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding] - [Success] [-]
Jun 13 00:12:28 db-k450-hd2-1 IngrianActivity: [2020-06-13 00:12:28] INFO 10.7.114.44 [-] - 204140000002 Crypto kestrel.database.key3 [op#1 DECRYPT DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding] - [Success] [-]
```

Comment: What software do you have running on the server? What is the server's purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You should first decide whether you need these messages or not. If they are useful, you need to make additional space available to log so that it doesn't fill. Or, you need to increase the frequency at which you rotate out old log files.

If you are sure that you do not need these messages, you may be able to reduce the application's (IngrianActivity) log level from INFO to WARN. That way, no messages at the INFO level will be written. Be very cautious about this as you don't want to miss relevant messages.